# Access file from gitolite-hosted git repository directly using http client

Tags: git, http, gitolite

I'm hosting git repositories with gitolite, and have setup both [ssh and http access](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html). I can clone repositories over ssh and http using the git cli. Now, I need to be able to load a file from the git repository over http without using the git client. Specifically, I need to provide the URL `https://git.example.com/myproject/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` to the [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) translation service so it can poll for changes to the `.po` messages file.

Is there a simple way to access this file directly using a http client?

An option I tried already: we are using Trac, which has a built-in source browser and provides links to raw files, but each URL is bound to a specific revision hash ([example](https://trac.strangecode.com/pulso/export/51e037aedb09735106f2e51520c3ff4430b663e3/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/default.po)), with no option to link to the "latest" file.

I've considered setting up a `post-receive` hook to export this file (or the whole repo) to a web-accessible location. However, I'd like to know if it is possible to access files directly in a repository via gitolite, not a workaround like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git models revisions as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (ie. connected nodes), not like a big stack of pancakes. There is no "latest" commit in Git. There's the newest commit by date, but that's probably not what you want, and it's not trivial to find. What you probably mean is the tip of the `master` branch.

Generally, [anything in Git that takes a hash (ie. `51e037aedb09735106f2e51520c3ff4430b663e3`) will also take a reference (ie. `master`)](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).  That URL can be tweaked to export the `master` version of that file.

https://trac.strangecode.com/pulso/export/master/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

Comment: Thanks @schwern. Using the Trac URL with the master reference works perfect, and is a workable solution for us. I'm still curious though, why it doesn't work (and how to make it work) to access a file directly when http requests are connecting to `gitolite-shell`. I can only assume the answer is simply because gitolite doesn't support that.